# How do I insert Bézier curves into an open image on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to draw some Bézier curves on an image I select to be displayed on a canvas, but I don't know how to do that. I have to select a curve in my select and the same should be inserted into the image. I would also be able to drag the curve into the image and change the position of the control points. To whom you can help me, I thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="image" name="selectImage" src="{{ asset('img/open.png') }}" 
onClick="openImageSelection()"><br>

<select id="curvesId" style="width: 80%; color:black">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option onclick="curve1()">Curve 1</option>
    <option onclick="curve2()">Curve 2</option>
    <option onclick="curve3()">Curve 3</option>
</select>

<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function openImageSelection() {
    window.open("{{ route('image.index') }}", "_blank", "width=600, 
    height=400");
}

function openImage(path, loadFunction) {
    img = new Image();
    image_url = path;
    let ctx = document.getElementById('image');
    ctx.setAttribute("onmousedown", "bezier_coordinate(event)");
    if (ctx.getContext) {
        ctx = ctx.getContext('2d');
        ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        ctx.canvas.height = 785;
        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1050, 785);    //draw background image
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(1, 1, 1, 0)"; //draw a box over the top
            if (loadFunction) {
                loadFunction();
            }
        };
    }
    img.src = path;
}

function bezier_coordinate(event) {
    const selectedIndex = document.getElementById("curvesId").selectedIndex;
    const currentCurve = 
    document.getElementById("curvesId").options[selectedIndex].text;
    if (currentCurve === "Selecione") {
        coordenadas(event);
    } else {
        bezier_curve(event, currentCurve);
    }
}

function image(path) {
    global_points = [];
    global_effects = [];
    openImage(path, null);
    reset();
}

function curve1(){
    // Define the points as {x, y}
    let start = { x: 20,    y: 40  };
    let cp1 =   { x: 230,   y: 30  };
    let cp2 =   { x: 150,   y: 80  };
    let end =   { x: 250,   y: 100 };

    // Cubic Bézier curve
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, end.x, end.y);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Start and end points
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(start.x, start.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);  // Start point
    ctx.arc(end.x, end.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);      // End point
    ctx.fill();

   // Control points
   ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(cp1.x, cp1.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);  // Control point one
   ctx.arc(cp2.x, cp2.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);  // Control point two
   ctx.fill();
}

function curve2(){
    // Define the points as {x, y}
    let start = { x: 50,    y: 20  };
    let cp1 =   { x: 200,   y: 15  };
    let cp2 =   { x: 100,   y: 60  };
    let end =   { x: 250,   y: 100 };

    // Cubic Bézier curve
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, end.x, end.y);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Start and end points
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(start.x, start.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);  // Start point
    ctx.arc(end.x, end.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);      // End point
    ctx.fill();

   // Control points
   ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(cp1.x, cp1.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);  // Control point one
   ctx.arc(cp2.x, cp2.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);  // Control point two
   ctx.fill();
}

function curve3(){
    // Define the points as {x, y}
    let start = { x: 100,    y: 40  };
    let cp1 =   { x: 230,   y: 60  };
    let cp2 =   { x: 120,   y: 80  };
    let end =   { x: 300,   y: 150 };

    // Cubic Bézier curve
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x, cp1.y, cp2.x, cp2.y, end.x, end.y);
    ctx.stroke();

    // Start and end points
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(start.x, start.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);  // Start point
    ctx.arc(end.x, end.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);      // End point
    ctx.fill();

   // Control points
   ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(cp1.x, cp1.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);  // Control point one
   ctx.arc(cp2.x, cp2.y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);  // Control point two
   ctx.fill();
}

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Page for image selection:

```
<style>
    img {
        height: 100px;
        margin: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

img:hover {
    border-color: #EA0404;
}
</style>

@foreach ($images as $image)
    <img src="{{ asset('radiografias/'.$image->path) }}" title="{{'Radiografia '.$image->id}}">
@endforeach

<script>
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");

    for (var x = 0; x < imgs.length; x++) {
        imgs[x].addEventListener("click", function () {
            window.opener.image(this.src); 
            window.close();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and other topics under "asking" in the help center. I would then suggest  writing some code for the `bezier_coordinate` function,and getting that to work  on a blank canvas, asking for further help if needed, before proceeding with images.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much. I've added the code of the Bezier_coordinate function.

Comment: You appear to be asking "how to edit bezier curves on a radiographic image?" which is much too broad, The added code does not appear tg edit anything. Please cut down the problem to single things we can help with. Also look for existing solutions for similar problems, e.g. using search terms like "canvas curve edit javascript"

Comment: PS.  As a thought you could also position a transparent  canvas for curves _on top of_ an image element and keep them separate during edit. This would, of course, require change to  program design.